# jQuery CSS Selector issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

In the following code, after the jQuery runs, I expected only 2 to be seen with background red.

However, after jQuery runs, I can see 1, 2 and 3 with their backgrounds red.

Where is the glitch?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div').css('display','block').css('background','red');
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div style="display:none">1</div>
    <div style="display:block">2</div> 
    <div style="display:none">3</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: What is the requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.css('display','block')` is not a selector, it's a `setter`. You set `display: block` to all `divs` and then set a red `background` to all too. It's called a `chain`.

```
$('div')     .css('display','block').css('background','red');
//^ selector  ^ first setter         ^ second setter
```

There are plenty of ways to select the correct `div`.

```js
$("div:visible").css({display: "block", background: "red"});
$("div").filter(":visible").css({display: "block", background: "red"});
$("div[style='display:block']").css({display: "block", background: "red"});
$("div:eq(1)").css("display", "block").css({display: "block", background: "red"});
$("div").eq(1).css("display", "block").css({display: "block", background: "red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:none">1</div>
<div style="display:block">2</div>
<div style="display:none">3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery is working correct, you have first set all divs to be block and then coloured them red.

If you only want to select the visible div to colour, try using the selector `:visible`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div:visible').css('background', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:none">1</div>
<div style="display:block">2</div>
<div style="display:none">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery code is overriding the inline style. Set which divs to be displayed from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.css('display','block')` :

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div:visible').css('background': 'red');
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div style="display:none">1</div>
    <div style="display:block">2</div> 
    <div style="display:none">3</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting them all and then setting the display as block with background red I think something like this

```
$('div:visible').css('background','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect only 2 to be seen with background red, Please try this.

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div').each(function(){    
                if ( $(this).css('display') == 'block')
                {
                    $(this).css('background', 'red');
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body>
```

Comment: Really, don't use `each` for such tasks!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. could you edit the html code without using each function for me?

Comment: Just take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612588/jquery-css-selector-issue/39612641#39612641).